# Getting Django admin url for an object

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

Before Django 1.0 there was an easy way to get the admin url of an object, and I had written a small filter that I'd use like this: `<a href="{{ object|admin_url }}" .... > ... </a>`

Basically I was using the url reverse function with the view name being `'django.contrib.admin.views.main.change_stage'`

```
reverse( 'django.contrib.admin.views.main.change_stage', args=[app_label, model_name, object_id] )
```

to get the url.

As you might have guessed, I'm trying to update to the latest version of Django, and this is one of the obstacles I came across, that method for getting the admin url doesn't work anymore.

How can I do this in django 1.0? (or 1.1 for that matter, as I'm trying to update to the latest version in the svn).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I would try to call `reverse('admin_index')` and was constantly getting `django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch` errors.

Turns out I had the old format admin urls in my urls.py file.

I had this in my urlpatterns:

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
```

which gets the admin screens working but is the deprecated way of doing it.  I needed to change it to this:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls) ),
```

Once I did that, all the goodness that was promised in the [Reversing Admin URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls) docs started working.

Comment: Awesome, this fixed another issue I was having with the get_urls() method of ModelAdmin not being called. Thanks!

Comment: best url for this problem: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

Comment: This "answer" is not correct it just shows how to properly add the admin app to your app, which solved a different problem that the author had. The real answer to the actual question is below - from markmuetz

Comment: Also, you need to have registered admin interface for the model, otherwise the URL won't exist.

Answer (score 543):

You can use the URL resolver directly in a template, there's no need to write your own filter. E.g.

`{% url 'admin:index' %}`

`{% url 'admin:polls_choice_add' %}`

`{% url 'admin:polls_choice_change' choice.id %}`

`{% url 'admin:polls_choice_changelist' %}`

Ref: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)

Comment: markmuetz - Is this in the official Django docs anywhere? (how to use admin reverse URLs in templates)? If not, it should be.

Comment: shacker - It's all in the docs... just not in one place. The "url" template tag is documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url). In the section "New in Django 1.1:" the docs say that namespaced URLs are fine, and points you to [the section on URL namespaces](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces). Sticking it all together lets you reference the admin application easily in templates.

N.B I remember the docs being different when I wrote the reply.

Comment: Do you know how to get a link to the "list" of choices? Example: if "{% url admin:polls_choice_add %}" gives "/admin/polls/choice/add" what would be the equivalent that would give me "/admin/polls/choice"?

Comment: {% url admin:polls_choice_changelist %} returns the '/admin/polls/choice' url

Comment: Reversing an admin url is currently fully documented here [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)

Comment: Note that in Django 1.5, you'll need to have the view name in quotes. E.g., `{% url "admin:index" %}`.

Comment: I spent the better part of a day looking for this answer.  It seems like there should be another question specifically for "How to get a Django admin app object change URL for an object in a template"

Comment: Is there a way to use the `url` tag with the flexibility of the OP's filter with parameters for the app name and model name?

Comment: My multi-word model names were causing a problem. Don't use an underscore between words, e.g. `MyChoice` would be `{% url 'admin:polls_mychoice_changelist' %}`

Answer (score 127):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
def url_to_edit_object(obj):
  url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (obj._meta.app_label,  obj._meta.model_name),  args=[obj.id] )
  return u'<a href="%s">Edit %s</a>' % (url,  obj.__unicode__())
```

This is similar to hansen_j's solution except that it uses [url namespaces](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#defining-url-namespaces), admin: being the admin's default application namespace.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. One thing i would change: use `args=[object.pk]` instead of `args=[object.id]`. It covers more common case, when primary key field has another name than `id`.

Comment: Good answer. FYI anyone using a more recent django will need to change 

object._meta.module_name
to
object._meta.model_name

Comment: Big thank you from a django newbie. `object._meta.app_label` let me ultimately get the name for django's own authentication app. It's `auth`, for example `reverse(admin:auth_user_change, args=[object.id])` to jump to the change user page

Comment: Be sure to change object to obj. This guy is over writing a reserved built in symbol.

Comment: even he can use "format_html" django method in django admin changeList page or within other pages: return format_html(f'<a href="{url}">{obj.bot.ea_username}</a>')

Answer (score 25):

Essentially the same as Mike Ramirez's answer, but simpler and closer in stylistics to django standard `get_absolute_url` method:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def get_admin_url(self):
    return reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (self._meta.app_label, self._meta.model_name),
                   args=[self.id])
```

Answer (score 20):

## Using template tag `admin_urlname`:

There's another way for the later versions (>=1.10), recommend by [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls), using the template tag `admin_urlname`:

```
{% load admin_urls %}
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'add' %}">Add user</a>
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' user.pk %}">Delete this user</a>
```

Where `opts` is something like `mymodelinstance._meta` or `MyModelClass._meta`

One gotcha is you can't access underscore attributes directly in Django templates (like `{{ myinstance._meta }}`) so you have to pass the `opts` object in from the view as template context.

Comment: The docs url has changed! See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

Comment: Since Wim's URL is dead, here's a working one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

Answer (score 18):

For pre 1.1 django it is simple (for default admin site instance):

```
reverse('admin_%s_%s_change' % (app_label, model_name), args=(object_id,))
```

Comment: With the new namespacing it's admin:%s_%s_change

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by changing the expression to:

```
reverse( 'django-admin', args=["%s/%s/%s/" % (app_label, model_name, object_id)] )
```

This requires/assumes that the root url conf has a name for the "admin" url handler, mainly that name is "django-admin",

i.e. in the root url conf:

```
url(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root, name='django-admin'),
```

It seems to be working, but I'm not sure of its cleanness.

Comment: This works for 1.0, but will not work for 1.1, which has a better solution: see Alex Koshelev's answer.

Comment: Actually I tried it and it didn't work, and he said it's for 1.0, no?

Comment: Syntax has changed in 1.1 with the introduction of url namespacing: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces

Answer (score 3):

If you are using 1.0, try making a custom templatetag that looks like this:

```
def adminpageurl(object, link=None):
    if link is None:
        link = object
    return "<a href=\"/admin/%s/%s/%d\">%s</a>" % (
        instance._meta.app_label,
        instance._meta.module_name,
        instance.id,
        link,
    )
```

then just use {% adminpageurl my_object %} in your template (don't forget to load the templatetag first)

Answer (score 0):

For going to the admin page or admin login page we can use the below link. It works for me -

```
{% url 'admin:index' %}
```

This url takes me directly to the admin page.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option, using models:

Create a base model (or just add the admin_link method to a particular model)

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    def admin_link(self):
        if self.pk:
            return mark_safe(u'<a target="_blank" href="../../../%s/%s/%s/">%s</a>' % (self._meta.app_label,
                    self._meta.object_name.lower(), self.pk, self))
        else:
            return mark_safe(u'')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Inherit from that base model

```
   class User(CommonModel):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=765)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=192)
```

Use it in a template

```
{{ user.admin_link }}
```

Or view

```
user.admin_link()
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. Building a URL with string formatting is a bad habit. Please use reverse().