# Linking to the django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-urls

Very basic question, but I'm having trouble tracking down the answer on the web. I have a template, which I want to link to the django admin site (i.e. localhost:8000/admin). What is the code for this?

I'm imagining something like

```
<a href="{% url admin.site.root %}">link to admin panel</a>
```

However, when I try the above snippet I get:

```
Caught an exception while rendering:
  Reverse for 'project_name.django.contrib.admin.sites.root' with
  arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Help?

Answer (score 126):

Try what Oggy is suggesting but then use ':' instead of '_' with the current Django:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">link to admin panel</a>
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. With Django 1.3, using `admin_index` gave me a `TemplateSyntaxError`: `Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'admin_index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` Using `admin:index` instead provided a working admin site URL.

Comment: For anyone coming here from Google, Django 1.5+ it's `{% url "admin:index" %}`, with the quotes

Comment: If you want to link to a subpage of the admin site, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930241/7221965)

Comment: What does 'admin:index' do and why do work other url paths in a different way (not with ":" )?

Answer (score 8):

Which django version are you using? If you're using trunk, change your admin urlpatterns from:

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root)
```

to:

```
('^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

And then you get a named URL pattern called 'admin_index' which you can refer to. See

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

for more information

Comment: url name is 'admin:index'