# How can I generate a url to a particular item in the Django Admin Site from a view?

Tags: django

I would like to make a link that would take the user to a particular  item in the admin site (assuming they have the correct permissions).

Something like: https://mysite/admin/app/model/id/

Can this be done with reverse?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694477/getting-django-admin-url-for-an-object/2930241#2930241

Comment: @second - that question is from the good old Django 1.0 days, so there's quite a lot of noise. I've tried to summarise the information below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the url in the view, using `reverse`,

```
object_change_url = reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_change', args=(obj.id,))
```

Or in the template, using the url tag

```
{% url 'admin:myapp_mymodel_change' obj.id %}
```

or

```
{% load admin_urls %}
{% url opts|admin_urlname:'change' obj.id %}">
```

Note the above url tag syntax is for Django >= 1.5.

For more information, see the Django docs on [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).

Comment: Is `obj` supposed to stand in here for your model? I got it to work by replacing `obj` with my model name, is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @DavidRhoden it’s a long time since I wrote the answer. Looking at the docs, I think it should be `opts` not `obj`

Comment: Thanks. Old answer, but it got me where I needed to go.