# Use .id in Django Template to Admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views, django-urls

Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls). I need help kicking in the `id` parameter under the `change` function, so that it reroutes the url to the correct admin edit page.

In a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930241/5853556), the following answer was listed:

```
{% url 'admin:polls_choice_change' choice.id %}
```

Did I wrap in `{% for %}` tags correctly? Am I supposed to?

my views.py:

```
def customer_details(request, id):
    var = model.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'vendor_db/vendors_detail.html', {'var': var,
    })
```

customer_details.html:

```
{% for items in var %}
   <a href="{% url 'admin:app_model_change' items.id %}">Edit</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

question was answered in comments, thanks for the help!

Comment: when you do `model.objects.get()` it returns a single instance not a list, if you do `model.objects.filter()` then you can do a `for loop`, just get rid of the `for loop` and use the `var.id`

Comment: But why do you want a for loop at all?

Comment: And of course `app` and `model` should be replaced with the name of your app and model.

Comment: @abhishekgarg You are right, it worked! All I needed was write was var.id in the template. Thanks a million!

Comment: @DanielRoseman The `for` loop was not needed, I thought I would have to wrap it in some sort of `{% %}` tag but it was already wrapped in `{% url ' ' %}` . Thank you for the insight!