# Reverse Django admin URLs

Tags: python, django, django-templates

As described [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930241/1440565), we can use the `url` tag to  reverse Django admin URLs. However, in the examples shown there, you need the app name and model name in the string passed to `url`. Is there a way to pass those in as parameters instead? What I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
{% url 'something here' app_name model_name object_id %}
```

What do I put for `'something here'`?

Comment: I suggest you install `django_extensions` and use its command to find URL names. `python manage.py show_urls`

Comment: @rabbit.aaron You should post that as an answer. Also, it will help to show an example to illustrate how that tool will answer my question.

Answer (score 23):

I suggest using `django_extensions` to use its `show_urls` command to find url names.

simply do

```
pip install django_extensions
```

then add `django_extensions` to your INSTALLED_APPS

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'django_extensions',
]
```

Then you can run

```
python manage.py show_urls
```

You can use it with `grep` to filter out the relevant URLs you need.
e.g.

```
python manage.py show_urls | grep password
/admin/auth/user/<id>/password/  django.contrib.auth.admin.user_change_password  admin:auth_user_password_change
/admin/password_change/  django.contrib.admin.sites.password_change      admin:password_change
/admin/password_change/done/     django.contrib.admin.sites.password_change_done admin:password_change_done
```

And say we want to use `django.contrib.auth.admin.user_change_password` in our template:

We can do:

```
{% url "admin:auth_user_password_change" user.pk %}
```

**P.S. You don't really need `django_extensions` for your production environment, so you probably want to install it locally for development use only.**

---

#### Resources:

[django_extensions installation documentation](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html#installation-instructions)
[django_extensions commands](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_extensions.html?highlight=show_urls)

Comment: Question: is the middle column the name of the function that is registered for that view? If so, can I use this name with the `url` tag or `reverse()`?

Comment: yes you can use the names with `reverse`. the colon specifies a namespace, look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: I'm referring to the names **in the middle "column"** such as `django.contrib.auth.admin.user_change_password`. (I don't see any colon here.)

Comment: For example, when I run `./manage.py show_urls`, I see a path such as `/my_app/my_model/<path:object_id>/change/       django.contrib.admin.options.change_view        admin:myapp_mymodel_change`. To reverse the `admin:myapp_mymodel_change` route, I have to hard code both the name of the app and the name of the model.  My question is if there is a way to pass both of these as parameters to `reverse()` (or `{% url %}`). From what I can tell there isn't. Of course, I can easily build my own function with some string formatting.

Comment: I don't think Django provide such feature. If you take a look at `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.get_urls`. You'll see how the URLs are generated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reverse admin urls, the default admin.sites.urls has a urlpattern in it that looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', wrap(self.index), name='index'),
        path('login/', self.login, name='login'),
        path('logout/', wrap(self.logout), name='logout'),
        path('password_change/', wrap(self.password_change, cacheable=True), name='password_change'),
        path(
            'password_change/done/',
            wrap(self.password_change_done, cacheable=True),
            name='password_change_done',
        ),
        path('jsi18n/', wrap(self.i18n_javascript, cacheable=True), name='jsi18n'),
        path(
            'r/<int:content_type_id>/<path:object_id>/',
            wrap(contenttype_views.shortcut),
            name='view_on_site',
        ),
    ]
```

Looking at the above code you can simply use `{% url 'admin:index' %}` in templete of `reverse('admin:index')` else where for the admin dashboard url. Likewise same with all other admin urls patterns

Comment: Thank you for the info. My original question was about the admin routes to a specific model in an app, such as the changeform view. The question I linked to shows examples with the app and model name included in the route name. However, I have a situation where I'd like to pass those as parameters instead. My question is asking how to do that.