# Wagtail: Add method to PageModel to get an inspect url

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to add a dynamic instead of a hard coded `get_inspect_url` method to a `PageModel`:

```
class MyModel(Page):
    # ...
    # this is what I have now, which breaks in prod due to a different admin url
    def get_inspect_url(self):
        inspect_url = f"/admin/myapp/mymodel/inspect/{self.id}/"   
        return inspect_url
```

I know that you can use the `ModelAdmin.url_helper_class` in `wagtail_hooks.py` to [get admin urls for an object](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/tips_and_tricks/reversing_urls.html#getting-the-edit-or-delete-or-inspect-url-for-an-object), but I can't figure a way to do the same on the model level as a class method. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Andrey Maslov tip I found a way:

```
from django.urls import reverse

    def get_inspect_url(self):
        return reverse(
            f"{self._meta.app_label}_{self._meta.model_name}_modeladmin_inspect",
            args=[self.id],
        )
```

The basic form of a Wagtail admin url is:

```
[app_label]_[model_name]_modeladmin_[action]
```

Just change the [action] to one of the following to generated other instance level admin urls:

- `edit`
- `delete`

Answer (score 0):

if you have in you urls.py line like this

```
path(MyModel/view/<id:int>/', YourViewName, name='mymodel-info'),
```

then you can add to your models.py this lines

```
from django.urls import reverse
...

class MyModel(Page):

    def get_inspect_url(self):
        inspect_url = reverse('mymodel-info', kwargs={'id': self.id})
        return inspect_url
```

Comment: I don't have an extra `view` associated with my model, since Wagtail takes care of that. So no distinct url path in `urls.py`. But I just figured another way: Importing my admin base url from my settings with `settings.WAGTAIL_ADMIN_URL` and put that in.

Comment: then may be this answer will be usefull for you [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930241/7186864](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930241/7186864)/ do the same with `reverse`